# How to display two-dimensional array in grid view with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to represent a two-dimensional array with some data in a grid, like a chessboard.
Lets say we have this 2d array:

```
val nums = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
)
```

My question is how can I display it with grid view and what would be the best approach. I will be glad to see some examples as well.
Im still new to Kotlin and some things are kinda confusing. I tried looking for similar solution, but nothing closer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
val nums = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    arrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
)
```

Convert 2D array into List

```
val yourList = ArrayList<String>()
var numOfRow : Int
nums.forEach{ col ->
 numOfRow = col.size() 
 col.forEach { row -> {
    yourList.add(row)
 }
}
```

make an instance of Recycler Adapter with Grid Layout Manager

```
val adapter = YourAdapter(yourList)
yourRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
yourRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, numOfRow)
```

Comment: One liner to convert the 2D array to 2D list (although you could just create lists to begin with). `val yourList = nums.map(Array<Int>::toList)`